Is there any way to draw on sharing content in MS Teams, WebEx and Zoom
I'm trying to create an application to draw some shapes into the sharing content when host share their window in MS Teams/WebEx/Zoom then both host and participants can see that drawn shapes. I'm thinking to use dll injection technology to add drawing into the windows directly so that when user share window will include the shapes inside it. But if so I need to inject to all applications that can be shared, this will be not really good because the applications can use different libs to render UI. Alternatively, I think can inject the dll to MS Teams to draw shapes on the sharing area directly but I can't find any documents/solutions relate to this article. Can any one show me how it work? Or are there any other approaches to solve this problem?

Your thought sound platform specific but the mentioned products are platform independent. I don't see doing dll injection an an Android device for example.  Those tools allow sharing so why don't simply draw on the shared Desktop or Window?

I don't really get what you mean on "simply draw on the shared window" ? What I want is when I share notepad window, I can add a complex shape into that by using my application so that participants can also see it

OBS Studio might be able to help with this. Here's the top link from a Google search, for instance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGEsOZMhd-g

Instead of sharing a specific application you could share your entire screen and use an app such as Windows Ink.

I have done for sharing entire screen already but the customer also want to see it when share windows so I need to investigate an approach

This is not an answer, you could have use the comment section under the question bloc.
